# Why do C++ standard library containers use memory pools, if apparently the malloc/free pair does the same job?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, malloc, pool

I've read that repetitive calls to `malloc`/`free` can be expensive and for this reason C++ standard library containers use memory pools rather than calling `free` in their destructors. Also, I've read, this means that the performance of C++ standard library containers can be higher than manually allocating and deallocating all necessary C-style arrays.

However, I'm confused about this, since now I'm reading in the C FAQ: ( http://c-faq.com/malloc/freetoOS.html )

> Most implementations of malloc/free do not return freed memory to the operating system, but merely make it available for future malloc calls within the same program.

This means that essentially the `malloc`/`free` functions try to do the very same job as the C++ standard library containers: They try to optimize repetitive claiming/reclaiming memory by keeping memory in a pool and then giving the program pieces of this pool on request. While I can see the benefits of such an optimization if performed once, my intuition tells me that if we start doing this on a few different layers of abstraction simultaneously the performance is likely to actually decrease - as we will be duplicating the same work.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: What you're misunderstanding here is that unless your job involves writing the C++ library itself, this should be of no concern to anyone. I could never recall that in the 20+ years of hacking C++ this is something that I really cared about, ever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This still doesn't prevent me from asking questions about "why is it constructed in this and not that way" out of plain curiosity or to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations of the standard library use memory pools.

In general, when you know the memory needs of a particular container, you might be able to do a better job of managing its memory than a general-purpose memory manager that doesn't know your container's specific needs.

For example, if you're using `std::list<int>` every node in the list is the same size, and having the container maintain a list of unused nodes (just two pointer assignments to add or remove a node to/from the free list) may be faster than releasing unused nodes back to the more general but more complex general-purpose memory manager used by new/delete (malloc/free).

Answer (score 0):

The general memory management utility called `malloc` is generally optimized for common case scenarios.
Since the system should support multiple processes, each behaving differently, this optimization might be excellent for some applications and not that good for others.
A general purpose allocator tries to consider the following generic guidelines:

- Maximizing Compatibility: An allocator should be plug-compatible with others; in particular it should obey ANSI/POSIX conventions.
- Maximizing Portability: Reliance on as few system-dependent features (such as system calls) as possible, while still providing optional support for other useful features found only on some systems; conformance to all known system constraints on alignment and addressing rules.
- Minimizing Space: The allocator should not waste space: It should obtain as little memory from the system as possible, and should maintain memory in ways that minimize fragmentation -- ``holes''in contiguous chunks of memory that are not used by the program.
- Minimizing Time: The malloc(), free() and realloc routines should be as fast as possible in the average case.
- Maximizing Tunability: Optional features and behavior should be controllable by users either statically (via #define and the like) or dynamically (via control commands such as mallopt).
- Maximizing Locality: Allocating chunks of memory that are typically used together near each other. This helps minimize page and cache misses during program execution.
- Maximizing Error Detection: It does not seem possible for a general-purpose allocator to also serve as general-purpose memory error testing tool such as Purify. However, allocators should provide some means for detecting corruption due to overwriting memory, multiple frees, and so on.
- Minimizing Anomalies

This snippet was taken from a great [document written by Doug Lea](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) about what is called **Doug Lea's malloc**, which was the de facto memory management algorithm for many years, and I think every programmer should read this.

On the contrary, when a container is created, many factors are known during compile-time, and even more can be predicted during run-time, for example, we knows the size of the objects we are going to hold.
Using this knowledge, standard containers were written to work well with general purpose allocators.